# The selected wizard couldnot be found

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Hi, I added a Android SdK and Google app engine plugin for my eclipse but when i create a new project by using "App engine connected AndroidProject" i got following exception

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android was unable to load class com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.wizards.NewAndroidCloudProjectWizard.
com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.wizards.NewAndroidCloudProjectWizard
```

How to over come the above issue..please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature from google is not ready yet. It won't work till they give us an update to the plugins.
See here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-plugin-eclipse/nz940DaWrKY